# Is it possible to let run Project.ImportDirectory(…) in silent mode?

Tags: c#, enterprise-architect

After opening my EA project via the automation API, the call of `ImportDirectory(…)` method brings up a window where the import progress is shown (the same like when performing a manual import):

```
var repo = new EA.RepositoryClass();
repo.OpenFile("some.eap");
var proj = repo.GetProjectInterface();

proj.ImportDirectory(…);
```

This is not very handy since I want to execute the import as part of a TFS build definition. Not only the fact that it shows a window, but mainly because I will need some UI Automation API (e.g. Ranorex) in order to dismiss popping-up warning/error dialogs and in order to close the form at the end.

Is there a way to make the import run in silent mode i.e. without the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Except those "extraoptions" offer a hidden workaround.

Comment: EA Support told me too that no silent mode exists. The sole properties being somehow related to silent mode are `Repository.SuppressEADialogs` and `Repository.EnableUIUpdates` which both do not affect the import though.

Comment: Somehow those guys at Sparx know how to spoil an API by not offering options that users really NEED. They just offer option, the marketing things, they were fancy :-(

Comment: To me it seems like the UI was built first and an API was designed afterwards. If they had designed the API first und used it from their own UI, we would be much better off...

Comment: EA has not been designed. It has grown over the years. It started with a little Access application written by Geoff. Around 2000 there was quite a lot interactive development with great user feedback. Later (around 2005 or so) marketing took over and things good bad.